# How can I run a ansible task only if a file or directory does NOT exist?

Tags: ansible

In an Ansible playbook I want to run tasks if a directory does **not** exists.

```
- name: Check for java exists in /opt     
  stat: path=/opt/jdk1.8.0_71
  register: p
  when: p.stat.isdir is defined and p.stat.isdir
```

But what must I do to ensure that the following tasks runs only if this dir does not exist?

```
- name: Extract java if dir not existing
  command: tar xzf /tmp/jdk1.8.0_71 chdir=/opt
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
- name: Extract java if dir not existing
  command: tar xzf /tmp/jdk1.8.0_71 chdir=/opt
  when: not p.stat.exists
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more how this works?  It's not clear what `p` or `stat` refer to.

Comment: @bonh see the question asked. It has everything you are asking for.

Comment: Sorry! Thanks, I need to drink more coffee.

Comment: I have just used this but have to check p.results.stat.exists in Ansible 2.7.5

Answer (score 75):

This is what the `creates` parameter is perfect for:

```
- name: Extract java if dir not existing
  command: tar xzf /tmp/jdk1.8.0_71 
  args: 
      chdir: /opt 
      creates: /opt/jdk1.8.0_71
```

Ansible will check to see if `/opt/jdk1.8.0_71` exists and only run the command if it does not exist.

[Command Module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/command_module.html)

You can also download and untar(if not exist) in the following way

```
    - name: "If jdk not exists then only download and unarchive"
      unarchive:
        src: "https://download.oracle.com/java/17/latest/jdk-17_linux-aarch64_bin.tar.gz"
        dest: /opt/
        remote_src: yes
        creates: /opt/jdk-17
      register: foo
    - name: "Rename if download happens "
      command: mv /opt/jdk-17_linux-arch64 /opt/jdk-17
      when: foo.changed == True
```

Ansible will skip the above task if `/opt/jdk-17` directory exists.

[Unachive module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/unarchive_module.html#parameter-creates)

Comment: And what if I need to eg. download /tmp/jdk1.8.0_71 before that command and want this task to also depend on whether /opt/jdk1.8.0_71 exists?

Comment: Updated link (posting as a comment because suggested edit queue is full):
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html

Comment: @Debilski you can use unarchive module, It is also updated on answers.